# How to implement file uploading with progress

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I am trying to implement the file uploading with progress but I can't find such ability in the framework (downloading can be implemented without any problem). 
I use such portable project's settings:

[image]

I need to use the PUT method and https protocol.

I found many articles but its don't work in the "portable space". For example I can't set ContentLength property of the WebRequest, I don't have WebClient object with ProgressChanged event, I found HttpClient for portable projects but I can't find good documentation about and can't understand how to use it for my goal.

Please suggest how I can achive my goal.

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of plug-ins that you can use in your project. one of them is uploadify

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: I use portable class library and such objects as WebRequest and WebResponse. How uploadify this plug-in can help me???